# NodeJS, Express. Cannot upload static content

Tags: node.js, express

I've tried to write node server which would run React app created by `create-react-app`. Actually, something strange happens and I don't have any clue what I'm doing wrong (run app as `node server/index.js`):

```
export default (app, dirname) => {
app.use(favicon(path.join(dirname, '..','build', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(dirname, '..','build')));


// initialize routers
bootRotes(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === AVAILABLE_ENVIROMENTS.DEVELOPMENT) {
    expressBootDev(app, dirname);
} else {
    app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(dirname, '..',  'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}
}
```

`build` folder contains build react app which created the following command `npm run build`

Strange things are happening when after uploading index page it tries to upload static content. For example `http://localhost:5000/static/js/2.30e86b6e.chunk.js`. Browser just adds `/` after each static content url and it turns to  `http://localhost:5000/static/js/2.30e86b6e.chunk.js/` and of course this url doesn't match to express.static middleware.
Moreover, I've checked via Postman, that url GET `http://localhost:5000/static/js/2.30e86b6e.chunk.js` withot `/` at the end provides content which is expected.

I work with PRODUCTION env, it means that expressBootDev doesn't have any impacts.

Has anybody has the same issue? I've spent whole day and don't know hopw to fix it.

When I'm creating a simple code in a root app folder with almost the same logic and run as `node server.js` and it works as expected:

```
//server.js
const express = require('express');
const favicon = require('express-favicon');
const path = require('path');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/build/favicon.ico'));

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
  return res.send('pong');
});
app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port);
```

And I don't see any principal difference

Comment: Can you provide your directory tree so we can see where files are?

Comment: Of course http://joxi.ru/Vrw4Xd3TOpKpVm

Comment: Does the build dir have a static dir which contains the index.html, js and such?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/E2p4KqVT95Bd42
`build` contains index.html, but `static` doesn't

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn I've extended the init post

Comment: in both of the examples, if you console.log the result of the path.join calls, what are the results for both code samples? I wonder if they have trailing slashes when using `..` notation.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// GET: Sent some basic info for usage
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

  var fname = __dirname + '/../public/index.html';

  var val = fs.readFile( fname, 'utf8', ( err, data) =>   {
        //send can only be called once, write can be called many times,
        // in short res.send(msg) == res.write(msg);res.end();
        res.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the example how you can do a static file serving with node.
https://github.com/msatyan/ApiServe1/blob/master/routes/index.js
The full project is 
https://github.com/msatyan/ApiServe1

FYI: Node.js with HTTP1 is not an efficient for static file serving by design, I believe HTTP2 support in node has addressed this problem. The reason for inefficiency with HTTP1 is that it has to take the file content read at native layer to JavaScript layer and then send it through HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't help me :(